# Xamarin test recorder script when run manually does not work.

Tags: xamarin

i have the following script that is attached is recorded using Xamarin Test recorder . When i re run the same script manually it gives error for the index .

Test script :

```
  public void NewTest2()
        {
             app.Tap(x => x.Class("FormsImageView").Index(6));
            app.Tap(x => x.Id("button2"));
            app.Tap(x => x.Class("CachedImageView").Index(3));
            app.Tap(x => x.Class("EntryEditText"));
            app.EnterText(x => x.Class("EntryEditText"), "9may client");
            app.Tap(x => x.Text("Añadir"));
            app.Tap(x => x.Class("CachedImageView").Index(8)); // this line 
            gives error
            app.Tap(x => x.Text("Third Touch Point"));
            app.Tap(x => x.Text("No"));
       }
```

i can send the apk..but not finding option to attach a file. 
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

If you open your Output view it should show an error ? Have you also tried changing your index manually ?

I had the same issue, I changed the index manually and everything worked